# Missing 64-bit support / Missing Push Notification Entitlement Phone

Tags: android, ios, iphone, xcode, cordova

I am trying to submit my app and I keep getting this issue. I have updated the Phonegap and cordova but still get his issue. I have also regenerated the app using command line after the update but no luck.

Email below.

> Dear developer,
>
> We have discovered one or more issues with your recent delivery for .
>   Your delivery was successful, but you may wish to correct the
>   following issues in your next delivery:
>
> Missing Push Notification Entitlement - Your app appears to include
>   API used to register with the Apple Push Notification service, but the
>   app signature's entitlements do not include the "aps-environment"
>   entitlement. If your app uses the Apple Push Notification service,
>   make sure your App ID is enabled for Push Notification in the
>   Provisioning Portal, and resubmit after signing your app with a
>   Distribution provisioning profile that includes the "aps-environment"
>   entitlement. See "Provisioning and Development" in the Local and Push
>   Notification Programming Guide for more information. If your app does
>   not use the Apple Push Notification service, no action is required.
>   You may remove the API from future submissions to stop this warning.
>   If you use a third-party framework, you may need to contact the
>   developer for information on removing the API.
>
> Missing 64-bit support - Beginning on February 1, 2015 new iOS apps
>   submitted to the App Store must include 64-bit support and be built
>   with the iOS 8 SDK. Beginning June 1, 2015 app updates will also need
>   to follow the same requirements. To enable 64-bit in your project, we
>   recommend using the default Xcode build setting of “Standard
>   architectures” to build a single binary with both 32-bit and 64-bit
>   code.
>
> After you’ve corrected the issues, you can use Xcode or Application
>   Loader to upload a new binary to iTunes Connect.
>
> Regards,
>
> The App Store team

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out that this is just a warning message. The App got accepted!

**Missing Push Notification Entitlement** - Did not matter as I did not use the notification functionality.

**Missing 64-bit support** - You have to have the latest version of phonegap

Thanks for your help guys

Answer (score 1):

Goto developer site & enable push notification In your ptovisioning profile for production , recompile with latest provisioning profile & resubmit it.

Regarding 64 bit support have you changd active architecture setting from build setting it should be standard atchitecture.

Comment: I've the same issue, but my architectures are standards, and the valid ones are "arm64 armv7 armv7s". Any idea?